# PhpSpreadsheet: How can I set cell text orientation?

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I'm finding a way to set the text orientation while using PhpSpreadsheet.

Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvQnz.png

But the only thing I found is setTextRotation.
When I use this method. The result will be https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUyH.png

How can I set the text orientation like the first image?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: You need to use textRotation

Comment: @ArifKhan but the text will be rotation. Not like the image.

Comment: setWrapText() should help 
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/

Comment: @ArifKhan if I use setWrapText(). I must set cell width, then I click to the cell, It is always small to edit text. Not like he text orientation, the cell is big when I click it.
Like this https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/90369101/169744248-bba0b2e9-3926-4847-abd1-088ee3af82a9.png